# What's the power supply for a Saris CycleOps PowerBeam Pro turbo trainer?

Tags: replacement, turbo-trainer, electric-power

A friend is moving, and gave me his old turbo trainer. I've got the body assembly and a head unit, but he couldn't find the matching power supply.

[image: CycleOps PowerBeam Pro with head unit]

It has a standard 5.5mm barrel connector, but there's no indication of the voltage, polarity or power consumption.

Where can one find this information?

It looks like what I have is an older version of [this](https://saris.com/products/powerbeam-pro-trainer). The only power supply I can find on their website is [this](https://saris.com/products/smart-trainer-power-supply) one, which explicitly says that it's *not* compatible with PowerBeam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cycling/comments/jgbdz0/does_anyone_have_a_cycle_ops_powerbeam_pro_ant/) has a [response from Saris](https://www.reddit.com/r/cycling/comments/jgbdz0/comment/g9rp143/) giving the exact specs:

> Good Morning,
>
> Thanks for reaching out to Saris about your trainer.
> Though we stopped making our PowerBeam trainers in 2016 and since then have run out of some replacement parts, such as the power cord, we do have specifications for the power cord that you could likely find a replacement for. The one you see online on our site would not work to clarify, but here are the specs below for you as you asked. I hope this still helps!
>
> Specs:
>
> 15 volt, 1.2 amp
>
> Switchcraft #760 style barrel jack
>
> Inner positive barrel

That should give you all the details you need, but in case you're also missing the manual, I found [an online copy](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1593529/Cycleops-Powerbeam-Pro.html?page=3#manual) of one for almost exactly the same unit.

[Switchcraft #760](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/393/760_765_cd-2943023.pdf), corresponds to 5.5mm external, and 2.5mm internal diameter barrel connector.

Comment: Thanks! That looks right!